# If $f \circ g$ is surjective, $g$ is surjective

Tags: functions

1. If $f \circ g$ is surjective, $f$ is surjective.
2. If $f \circ g$ is surjective, $g$ is surjective.

$\textbf{Part 1:}$ Let $f:B \to A$ and $g:C \to B$. Assume $f \circ g$ is surjective. Since $f(g(x))$ is surjective, for all $a \in A$ there is a $c \in C$ such that $f(g(c))=a$. But since $g(c) \in C$ (by definition of g), that means for all $a \in A$, there is a $b \in B$ (namely g(c) such that f(b)=a). So f is surjective.

$\textbf{Part 2:}$ How would I amend the proof for Part 1 for Part 2?

Comment: Your domains and codomains do not make sense as is.

Comment: Oh I see why. Because of the composition. Would I have to amend the proof?

Comment: Well, first you should consider whether 2 is even true or not.

Answer (score 5):

The point $2.$ is **false**.

Example : Take $f(x)=\min(1,2x),g(x)=x/2$ from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$. $(f\circ g)(x)=x$ is surjective, but $g$ is not.

This way is true, however: I call that the **SI** (S on the left, I on the right) lemma as a reminder :

If $f\circ g$ is **S** urjective, then $f$ is surjective ($f$ is on the left, S is on the left)

If $f\circ g$ is **I** injective, then $g$ is injective ($g$ is on the right, I is on the right)

Comment: @Bryan oops thanks

Comment: I like the name 'SI lemma' though. I'm going to adapt it to 'EM lemma' for epimorphisms and monomorphisms. Thanks for a mnemonic.

Comment: An easier counterexample is $A=\{0\}$, $B=\{1,2\}$, $C=\{3\}$; $f\colon B\to C$ where $f(1)=f(2)=3$, $g\colon A\to B$ where $g(0)=1$. Then $f\circ g$ is injective and surjective, but $g$ is not surjective and $f$ is not injective.

Comment: I was very confused about your SI lemma prior to your edit. It makes much more sense now :-) I'll see if my long-term memory is capable of accepting any new mnemonics...